# How to change the layout of posts when viewing all posts by tag

Tags: posts, themes, tags

In Wordpress, tags are applied to our posts. When I view a post, at the bottom are the associated tags. If I click one of the tags, I am taken to a view that shows all posts with that tag.

The view that is displayed shows each post's entire contents in long, narrow, unflattering columns and oversized fonts. I want to customize the layout of this.

We use the Undsgn Uncode theme, and I'm not sure if it is a part of the theme, or a common setting/feature somewhere in Wordpress. Sorry, I'm a Wordpress newb and do not know where to find options that control this particular view.

Comment: It's most likely something in the theme, and you should contact the theme's support team on this topic. But if you need to look into it yourself, the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#tag) shows that the tag archive page will be one of these files in the theme: `tag-{slug}.php`, `tag-{id}.php`, `tag.php`, or `archive.php`. If none of those are present, it'll use `index.php`. Most likely, IMHO, it'll be `tag.php` or `archive.php`.

Comment: @PatJ Yes, thank you. Your comment led me to search for the proper terminology and find the solution. I was able to change the "archive" layout options in the theme options.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got it fixed. Sometimes it's just a matter of knowing the right keywords to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the functionality was found in archive.php which is part of the Uncode Theme we are using.

The view with posts filtered by tags is called a posts archive and Uncode provides options to change the layout of various "archives" in the theme options. It involved creating a new content block with the desired layout and then changing the theme options to use the new content block for the "Posts Archive."